# Apache 2.4 on Fedora 20 not indexing the directories in the documentroot

Tags: apache, fedora20

i've got a problem with apache on Fedora and the problem is the following.

I've left i untouched for sometimes lately, let's say one year, i've always made the software updates but i expected that the configuration did not change, instead they did.

Being more specific let's say that i had two project on my server one year ago, and the virtualhost was set to index so that i could see the project as directories at server startup and go inside every  project quickly, but know the configuration is kind of lost or overwritten as i see a page coming from /urs/share/noindex insted of my projects directory when i type localhost in the browser and i cannot even access the directories inside the project cause it gives me "permission denied"..

Is it a permission problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the software updates, that in fedora adds a configuration file:

```
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome" page if there
# is no default index page present for the root URL.  To disable the
# Welcome page, comment out all the lines below. 
#
# NOTE: if this file is removed, it will be restored on upgrades.
#
#<LocationMatch "^/+$">
#    Options -Indexes
#    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
#</LocationMatch>

#<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
#    AllowOverride None
#    Require all granted
#</Directory>

#Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
```

Beware of that you all.. It made me loose 2 hours...